# Python: Appending list with Db values

Tags: python

I am relatively new in Python so facing difficulties in basics. I have following code that prints proper list value within loop but outside of loop it only shows the last value:

```
for item in statusEntries:
        theNameStatus = item[3] #get the numStatus field data
        if theNameStatus == 1:
            numStatus1 = item[2] #get cntStatus
        elif theNameStatus == 2:
            if numStatus1 > 0:
                theNameStatus = "closed"

        sctStatus["nameStatus"] = theNameStatus
        sctStatus["IDstatus"] = item[0]
        sctStatus["cntStatus"] = item[2]
        #Appending Status Array with Status Attribute Object
        sctResponse["STATUSOPTION"].append(sctStatus)
```

When I print **sctResponse["STATUSOPTION"]** within loop then it shows proper values with each iteration but when it reaches on last iteration it just fills it with last loop values:

```
{'STATUSOPTION': [{'nameStatus': 1, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 6}]}
{'STATUSOPTION': [{'nameStatus': 2, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 1}, {'nameStatus': 2, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 1}]}
{'STATUSOPTION': [{'nameStatus': 3, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 7}, {'nameStatus': 3, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 7}, {'nameStatus': 3, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 7}]}
{'STATUSOPTION': [{'nameStatus': 4, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 4}, {'nameStatus': 4, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 4}, {'nameStatus': 4, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 4}, {'nameStatus': 4, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 4}]}
```

**{'STATUSOPTION': [{'nameStatus': 5, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 5}, {'nameStatus': 5, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 5}, {'nameStatus': 5, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 5}, {'nameStatus': 5, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 5}, {'nameStatus': 5, 'cntStatus': 0, 'IDstatus': 5}]}**

As you can see the last bold record, all values wipied out and it filled it with last record. Why is it happening? Append should append rather than wiping it out, No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the loop is as you've shown it, then it looks to me like there's only one `sctStatus` dictionary, and you keep changing its `"namestatus"`, `"IDstatus"`, and `"cntStatus"` key-value pairs.  Try inserting `sctStatus = {}`, i.e.

```
    sctStatus = {}
    sctStatus["nameStatus"] = theNameStatus
    sctStatus["IDstatus"] = item[0]
    sctStatus["cntStatus"] = item[2]
```

so that you're appending a new dictionary each time.

Answer (score 2):

The reference to `sctStatus` is always a reference to the *same* dictionary - when you `append` that dictionary to the `sctResponse` list you are not appending a *copy* of the dictionary but rather a *reference* to it.  Either change the last line to `sctResponse["STATUSOPTION"].append(sctStatus.copy())` or create a new `sctStatus` dictionary each time.

```
status_option = []
sctStatus = {}
for i in range(1, 3):
    sctStatus["integer"] = i
    status_option.append(sctStatus)
    print "Round", i, "->", status_option
```

will print:

```
Round 1 -> [{"integer": 1}]
Round 2 -> [{"integer": 1, "integer": 2}, {"integer": 1, "integer": 2}]
Round 3 -> [{"integer": 1, "integer": 2, "integer": 3},
            {"integer": 1, "integer": 2, "integer": 3},
            {"integer": 1, "integer": 2, "integer": 3}]
```

What happened? Python is [pass-by-name](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-passing/) - unless you are dealing with a primitive value you are almost always passing these pseudo-pointers around by value.  When you append `sctStatus` to the list you are appending a *name* that still points at the same `sctStatus` dictionary in memory.  And when you alter that dictionary all of the names that point at it now pull up the *changed* dictionary.

See also [*Other Languages have variables*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) for another good explanation of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. THough the other solution was shorter and simpler hence got selected.